# How can I pull specific information about one element in a PowerShell table

Tags: powershell, ethernet, mtu

Sorry if the title isn't the best header, I wasn't sure how to word the question. But I am wanting to pull only information on the `NlMtuByes` section of a table PowerShell presents when I type the command `get-netipinterface -addressfamily "IPv4"`. The line of code im looking to incorporate with that information is the following.

`Get-NetIPInterface -interfacealias "Ethernet*" -addressfamily "IPv4" | ForEach-Object(If(NlMtuBytes -eq "1500"){Write-Host "Good to Go"}`

Comment: I am not sure if I got you right, but are you looking for `Get-NetIPInterface -interfacealias "Ethernet*" -addressfamily "IPv4" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Nlmtu`?

Comment: or better to have only the one "good to go" : `Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias "Ethernet*" -AddressFamily IPv4 | Where NlMtuBytes -eq 1500` You don't get only the value here but you have only the ones it seems to be useful to you. As @Vivek Kumar Singh said, you can add `| Select-Object -ExpandProperty Nlmtu` if you want only `1500` since you have tested an equality.